# Is there anyway to change the message body type from byte[] to string

Tags: rebus

Is there anyway to change the Transport message body type from byte[] to string. Having so will help users to see the content of the queue messages and also helps in writing  messages in to the queue(only for certain support scenarios). All this is needed because we trying to extend the transport to use TIBCO EMS queues for our solution.
Please advise.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - your options depend on the chosen serializer, though.

If you're using the built-in JSON serializer, you'll find the [rebus-encoding](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/Shared/Headers.cs#L66)-header on the message. The header indicates which encoding was used to transform the JSON `string` to a `byte[]`.

Comment: Thanks Mookid. this will still show encoded messages using the tibco ems queue explorer(GEMS) or websphere mq explorer (any jms for instance) which are not readable and editable. Is there anyway to write plain text strings as messages like in case of NSB. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well, you can't really avoid having bytes underneath it all - the question is how to tell your queue explorers how to decode the bytes. When dealing with unicode strings, your best default choice will usually be UTF8. Isn't it something you can configure in the explorers - something like a "default string encoding" or something like that?